# Ms access "invalid record set status" error

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, resultset, jdbc-odbc

I connect to my access database successfully and my sql is works and after these i have a result set. Code is below:

```
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sqlStr ="select max(ID) from GuestBook ";
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
```

But when i want to get value from resultset like this;

```
            int id = rset.getInt(1);
```

or

```
            int id = rset.getInt("ID");//or "max(ID)"
```

I have a sql exception.

Exception is "invalid record set status"

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column name of `"Expr1000"` will be generated for `max(ID)`. But I think that it is better to use an `As` clause to give it a well defined alias.

You must call `rset.next()` in order to move to the first row, because initially, the cursor is positioned before the first row.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sqlStr ="SELECT max(ID) As LastID FROM GuestBook";
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr);
int id = 0;
if (rset.next()) {
    id = rset.getInt("LastID");
    // OR
    id = rset.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. int id = rset.getInt("LastID"); not worked but the other one works.

Comment: *"Access creates a column name of "MaxOfID" for the aggregate function." - The query builder in Access does that for you, but if you use raw SQL (as in the question) and don't specify a column alias then the column is named [Expr1000].

Comment: @GordThompson: Ok, I changed the text. (I must confess, I never used jdbc, just got the information from googling.)